# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal - when try to save in database

Tags: javascript, html, database

Here when I trying to save description with new line, and try to save in database:

```
<textarea id="calendarDescripton" name="calendarDescription" style="width:355px;"></textarea>
```

and in save event i have:

```
var calendarDescription = $('#calendarDescripton').val();
```

got this error when I tried to save this description:

This is

descripion

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
>
> $('#calendarDescription').val('This is
>
> description');

I tried to add this in function save event, but nothing happens:

```
calendarDescription = calendarDescription.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
```

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you have a hardcoded val? The line you have does not match the error message

Comment: Ok i will printscreen what Im doing:
http://prntscr.com/anzzlt

and error is:
http://prntscr.com/ao004r

Comment: Where is that in your actual code? Show your full code.

Comment: You are somehow creating code from user input... You're either using `eval()` or your printing code with PHP. In either cases, you haven't provided the least context to help you.